# Sent emails have random sender email address

Tags: email

A family member of mine is responding to my emails from different email addresses which are not hers.

e.g. I sent an email from "me@myprovider.com" to "grandma@herprovider.com". I received two responses from her, one from "grandma@herprovider.com", which contains no text, and one from "real.name@herprovider.com". This email contains the message she wrote.

Till now this happened twice, with two different unkownresponding email addresses.

My grandma is not using different email adresses on purpose. She uses a pc with Windows7 and Outlook. What is a common way to investigate this problem? At which points could the email address be changed?

Comment: Contrary to your question, I would certainly not qualify this as random.  It is probably a bad configuration or corruption in her email program, and quite unlikely a security issue.  Checking the received mail headers might confirm that.

Comment: Definitely you need to check her pc to see which accounts are logged in.